# call class variable python django

Tags: python, django

I'am new to OOP in python and trying to use a class variable within the django framework. I need to call the class variable required and input it in the Charfield method like tihs:

```
class customerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, required=True):
        self.required = required
    
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=20)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=50, required=)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=50, required=)
    company_name = forms.CharField(label='Company Name', max_length=50, required=)
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address', max_length=100, required=)
    city = forms.CharField(label='City', max_length=50, required=)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class customerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, required=True):
        self.fields['name'].required = True
```